# MySQL crash with fatal error: InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool

Tags: mysql, innodb

First off: apologies for being what seems like the millionth user to have asked this question. I'm new to working with servers.

The MySQL service appears to be crashing a few times per day. Here is the error log containing what seem to be the pertinent errors:

```
2016-09-19 09:09:53 8461 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
2016-09-19 09:09:53 8461 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2016-09-19 09:09:53 8461 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-09-19 09:09:53 8461 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-09-19 09:09:53 8461 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-09-19 09:09:53 8461 [ERROR] Aborting
```

It seems the solution is invariably to increase the innodb_buffer_pool_size. The problem is, this setting, nor any other InnoDB settings, appear in any of my MySQL configuration files. All I can find is the following, in the **mysqld.cnf** file:

```
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
```

Some context: I'm running a single Wordpress site on a vps with 512M of RAM. I increased the RAM to 1G, but the problem persisted. Here are the memory usage details:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           992        896         96         44         19        133
-/+ buffers/cache:        743        249
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Can I simply add the following to the MySQL config file and decrease the buffer pool?:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size =
```

Is it necessary to set up a swapfile?

Comment: Since you do not have enough memory, you should decrease the buffer pool, not increase it,

Comment: What size would you suggest?

Comment: Refer to [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size) about figuring out what this setting should be.

Comment: @castis showed you the topic that describes how to calculate the recommended size from a performance point of view. How much to actually set it in case of your particular case we cannot possibly tell. But this question is more for DBAs, not for sw developers.

Comment: 1GB is a "tiny" machine.  I suggest trying 40M for the buffer_pool.

Comment: Have you tried on a different server?